# How do I set the Java path in Eclipse so I can run it on an external drive?

Tags: java, eclipse, portable-applications

I have Eclipse 3.5.1 and Java Portable (from Portableapps.com) installed on a portable hard drive and would like to point my Eclipse to use the portable apps Java version.  This will allow me to use Eclipse on a computer even if Java isn't installed.  How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps take a look at the [Eclipse Portable](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipseportable/) project on SourceForge

---

**EDIT**:
[Alternatively](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse?), edit the [eclipse.ini](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) file and add:

```
-vm 
..\path-to-jre\bin\javaw.exe
```

*[The new line after -vm matters]*

Comment: I've been following their progress, but don't want to use anything that's not "official" for my day job.  Once it officially hits and I can be sure it's stable and works well I'll definitely be using it.

Comment: Just noticed your edit.  Will try this tomorrow and see how that works.  Thanks.

Comment: Adding "-vm ..\path-to-jre\bin\javaw" to eclipse.ini doesn't seem to have any effect.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Adding "-vm ..\path-to-jre\bin\javaw" as an argument worked, but I am unable to get this to work with my portable apps menu.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm assuming you are replacing "..\path-to-jre" with the actual relative path to the potable JRE, right?

Comment: Yes, I'm specifying the path, not just copy/pasting.

Comment: As stated in the wiki, you must NOT use quotes around the path when using the .ini file. Perhaps that was the problem?

Comment: Guess I'm just going to have to wait for Eclipse Portable to be officially released then.

Answer (score 9):

I know it's been ages since this post has been active, but I might have three additional details to contribute (at least they seemed to be crucial in my case):

1. Just as stated [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse?#eclipse.ini), paths need to be separated by `/`, **not** `\` in `eclipse.ini`
2. At least on MS Windows 7 (64 bit), it seems to be very important that you put the `-vm ../path-to-jre/bin/javaw.exe` at the very **beginning** of the `eclipse.ini` file and that it is actually **two** lines:

   -vm

   ../path-to-jre/bin/javaw.exe

   Otherwise Eclipse seems to first try to find `C:\Windows\System32\javaw.exe` which will cause an error (at least my error log says so)
3. Seems that the following path (found [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/503269/vc/Eclipse-start-return-exit-code)) also works: `../path-to-jre/bin/server/jvm.dll`

As of 2013-04-19 for Eclipse 4.2.2 (Juno), this is how my `eclipse.ini` looks like:

```
-vm 
c:/jre/Java64/bin/javaw.exe
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Note that `/Java64/bin/javaw.exe` is taken from [portable java](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/java_portable)

Answer (score 2):

Open Eclipse.

Navigate to Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs

Add the JRE on your portable hard drive

Set this as your default JRE.

Comment: Is the the Java path it uses to RUN Eclipse?  The description in the menu states "...the checked JRE is added to the build path of newly created Java projects".  That doesn't sound like what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Indeed, I misunderstood. I'm guessing @amro's solution of modifying the .ini file may have some merit for your case.