# Eclipse thinks I only have Java 1.6, but when checking java-version in terminal it displays 1.7. Help :)

Tags: java, eclipse

I just downloaded Eclipse, and it said "Version 1.7 or greater is required" for Java. Then I downloaded Java 1.7 and installed it and all that, and even restarted my computer. When I check my Java version in the terminal, it says Java 1.7, so why can't Eclipse recognize Java 1.7?

Thanks a lot! :)

My question isn't a duplicate of [Running Eclipse on Mac - JVM Version 1.7 or greater is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387267/running-eclipse-on-mac-jvm-version-1-7-or-greater-is-required) because I installed the entire JDK 7 and my computer recognizes Java 1.7. Right now, I can't even open Eclipse.

EDIT:
current steps I have taken:

1) finding the path (/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home) to java 1.7 with command "/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7"

2) pasting this path by adding the following in the eclipse.ini file,

> -vm
>
> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home

Error message is still:

> Version 1.6.0_65 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version: 1.7 or greater is required.

Comment: There isn't a lot of information to go on here. How is your build environment configured? Are you talking about the Java runtime or the jdk?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387267/running-eclipse-on-mac-jvm-version-1-7-or-greater-is-required

Comment: You can change your version to JDK 7 explicitly in eclipse.

Comment: I dont know how my build environment is configured... :( Sorry! Literally just downloaded Eclipse and when I click on the application it won't open because it thinks my Java version isn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you must have done this but just in case you haven't can you make sure the environment variable's are set for Java

Comment: Sorry, what does this mean?

Comment: Have a look at this link and let me know if the path is set. If it still doesn't work do let me know. https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Comment: I'm using a mac and putting in "java -version" gives me "java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)". Does that mean the path is set?

Comment: no worries, kindly go through this link of how it is done on a mac
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842743/setting-java-home-environment-variable-on-mac-osx-10-9
If you are still stuck do let me know

Comment: Ok, so I'm sure that the path is set to Java 1.7 now. I followed the instructions on the link you provided as well. I feel like my computer is good with 1.7, but for some reason, Eclipse won't recognize Java 1.7...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs`?

There you can add (Using the Standard VM option) a JDK (or JRE) by setting the path to the JDK install directory.

Comment: Is this 'window' from Eclipse? Because I can't open Eclipse :( But for my macbook's system preferences, when I check on Java, it's version 1.7

Comment: Hmmm... Now I feel like things don't make sense. So I edited the eclipse.ini file and added in "-vm 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home" in two lines. I found the path to my JDK using the command "/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7". Thus, the path eclipse uses to find java has explicitly been set to version 1.7. When I click on the Eclipse to launch it, however, the message is "Version 1.6.0_65 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version 1.7 or greater is required."

Answer (score 0):

right click on

> project --> properties --> java compiler

and see the jdk compiler compliance  level option set to 1.7 compiler, if not change it to 1.7 or higher

EDIT :-

eclipse by default will take java installation path from %JAVA_HOME% variable, firstly you check whether you have set JAVA_HOME path in your machine.

or you can manually set java path in eclipse.ini file as said in this post

[How do I set the Java path in Eclipse so I can run it on an external drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580902/how-do-i-set-the-java-path-in-eclipse-so-i-can-run-it-on-an-external-drive)

and

[How to specify jdk path in eclipse.ini on windows 8 when path contains space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174265/how-to-specify-jdk-path-in-eclipse-ini-on-windows-8-when-path-contains-space)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having Eclipse already open? I can't open Eclipse at all

Comment: Sorry, how do I check for the JAVA_HOME path?

Comment: Is eclipse.ini a file I'm supposed to have? I tried searching for it and I don't think I have it? Sorry for all the trouble!

Comment: yes eclipse.ini file is must, i have used on my windows lap, for mac, check this post for the file location http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454889/eclipse-ini-file-not-present

Comment: So I've found eclipse.ini. I go to the terminal and check whereis java, and I get '/usr/bin/java'. Now I edit eclipse.ini, and I add '-vm 
../usr/bin/java' to the beginning of the file in two lines. When I try to open Eclipse now, it says, no Java virtual machine was found after searching '../usr/bin/java'. Does this mean the path I put into eclipse.ini is wrong? How do I find the path? Thanks SO much!!

Comment: you java installation path should also have jre folder inside. if not you will get this error

Comment: hmm... so after reading your comment, i just downloaded JRE 7. Now I just have a jre folder in my downloads. How would I move it into the java installation path? Thanks so much! Sorry I don't know how to do anything...

Comment: try mapping the eclipse.ini to jre path, and start you eclipse